# store files in a remote server Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-storage

I have a model where I have FileField to upload some documents. I save the files into my filesystem. I want to know if is possible to save the files in another server using ftp or another method.
For example my django app server run in the host 192.168.0.1 and I want to store the files in the host with the IP 192.168.0.2.

I can access without any problem through ftp to the server where I want to store the files.

Models:

```
class Documentacion(models.Model):
      id_doc = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      id_proceso = models.ForeignKey(Proceso,db_column='id',verbose_name='Proceso')
      tipo_docu = odels.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False,verbose_name='Tipo Doc.')
      fecha = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
      autor = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False)
      descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)
      documento = models.FileField(upload_to='docs/')
```

My MEDIA settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you go throught the docs, [FileField#upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) it's only to define a local filesystem path.

One thing you can do is: let the user uploads the content normally then when you have it in your filesystem run a process to upload the file to another server, aka your ftp server, you could use the [ftplib](http://effbot.org/librarybook/ftplib.htm) library to archieve this.

Maybe using [Django Storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) will ease your work.

Comment: I was thinking the same but when the user try to download the file how can I get the file from the ftp with django app.

Comment: You will have the url of the file right?, if so, it should be something trivial, just read the file and retrieve it by HTTP.

Since you should be writing or using a FileField extension or a custom Field, you will have expose methods like "File#path" or "File#url" as in FileField.

Again django-storages make use of FileField you just need to pass "storage=FTPStorage()" as parameter to use FTP and since it's a FileField you have all the methods from it.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try what you suggest. Very helpfull

Comment: Well doesn't work and the Django-storages documentation don't explain in a clearly way how to configure the ftp credentials and IP direction

Comment: Did you set: "FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = '[a]ftp://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/[path]'" on your settings.py file?.
[Check out the source code.](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/src/1323aca7e7065880046ae0e708172cf68528cace/storages/backends/ftp.py?at=release)

Comment: yes, but the always store the files in the folder specified in the MEDIA_ROOT. And when I commented the MEDIA_ROOT and in the FTP was empty but the database have the record